# How to change the alignment of a newly created primitive object

Tags: mesh

When I add cubes, for example, this always happens in view mode, regardless of which view mode I choose.

How is this possible ? [image]

Answer (score 5):

After adding a new cube, open the last action editor and set the Align option to World instead of View.

[image: last action editor]

Comment: That works, thank you very much !

Comment: @MIck If that works, please consider to accept the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Worth noting the OP is using  2.7x or before (screenshot) , in which case the operator properties panel is at the bottom of LHS tool shelf.